# Choosing ruby version that Aptana recognize?

Tags: ruby, aptana

I m using RVM in ubuntu to cope with ruby versions and I have two version of ruby, 1.8,7 and 1.9.2. I choose 1.8.7 by RVM but this change i not recognized by aptana and it's still using 1.9.2. When I restart it, still same.

How can I change the ruby version that Aptana recognize?

Thanks

Comment: tried `rvm use 1.8.7 && <script-to-start-aptana>` ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved by simple command with additional option "default"

```
rvm use 1.8.7 --default
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Users:

Install the version you want to switch to (e.g From `Ruby200-x64` to `Ruby22-x64`). Append the path to `Ruby22-x64` (e.g `C:\Ruby22-x64\bin`). Aptana always uses the latest one.

Note: You may need to restart the PC.